# ImportError: No module named jupyter_core.command when running via SSH

Tags: jupyter-notebook, conda

Jupyter notebook work just fine on my computer, but when i run it via ssh from another computer i receive this message:

```
ImportError: No module named jupyter_core.command
```

Im using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS for both of them 
and i have Conda installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok then.
I just installed Ipython outside of the environment i worked with.:

```
conda deactivate
```

and then:

```
sudo apt install ipython
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
sudo apt install python3-jupyter-core
```